# Getting class containing method

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection

I'm writing a method decorator and require access to the class defining the method that is currently decorated.

The issue seems with this is, that with Python 3 methods in a class are just functions unless the class is instantiated.

Is there any way around this? I don't really want to fiddle around with `__qualname__`...

```
In [29]: class A:
   ....:     def B(self):
   ....:         pass
   ....:     

In [30]: A.B.__qualname__
Out[30]: 'A.B'

# This is what I want:
>>> get_class(A.B)
A
```

Comment: Why not create a class decorator instead? When decorating functions in a class body, *the class is yet to be created*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters because the decorator changes the semantics of the decorated method *relative to the containing class*. `@decorate("some_method")\nclass Foo: ...` seems very counter-intuitive. If there is no alternative to it, I'll create a custom base class or metaclass and check attributes of all methods in there. Or something similar.

Comment: @Michael0x2a: No, that is not a correct duplicate. A function decorator on a method cannot determine the class *yet* because there is no class object until all functions have been defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because at the time your decorator on a method is run, *the class is yet to be created*.

An example illustrates this a little better:

```
class Foo:
    @spam
    def bar(self): pass
```

When `spam(bar)` is invoked to produce a decorated function, we are inside the pseudo-function  that Python runs to define the class body. Only when that pseudo-function is done executing, is the local namespace of that function turned into the class body and the actual class object itself is created.

That means that there is no `Foo` class object yet at the time `spam()` is run.

Instead, create a class decorator:

```
@spam
class Foo:
    def bar(self): pass
```

Now `spam()` is passed the whole, complete `Foo` class giving you access to both the class and the methods.

If you need to mark specific methods on the class for decoration, you could use a marker decorator that sets attributes on the function:

```
def marker(func):
    func._marked = True
    return func
```

Use this decorator in the class body on methods that you want decorated, then use the class decorator to pick out those methods:

```
@spam
class Foo:
    @marker
    def bar(self): pass

    def baz(self): pass
```

Comment: But, can't the decorator use the `self.__class__.__name__` to achieve this?. I mean, the op doesn't mentions what's the decorator gonna do.

Comment: @PauloBu: once bound you already have the class; `type(self)`, no need to go grab the name too. That is not the issue here.

Comment: Sorry, I just add `.__name__` to make my point. What I was referring is -- I have the doubt -- that it's possible for a method decorator to access the method's class by using the `self` parameter. He can still use a method decorator and have access to its class. Even if _the class is yet to be created_, when the method is executed, the decorator just access the `self.__class__` and he can work with that.

Comment: @PauloBu: This is not about executing the method after decoration. This is about accessing the class *during* decoration. There is no class yet at that time.

Comment: @PauloBu: and what about static methods? Those ignore the class reference when binding.

Comment: I understand your point and the suggestion you make. I only questioned it because as far as I can see, the OP doesn't say he needs to access the class during _binding time_ nor _execution time_. He only says _he needs access to the class from within the decorator_.

Comment: I resolved this now like you suggested earlier on by just leaving a marker on the decorated method that is then processed in `__init__` (b/c I managed to rephrase my "problem" into a form where I don't even need the class, but a live instance). Background was btw. to create a few decorators easing AOP. One of those is used to decorate a aspects' method so as to inject the method into the advised class.